# How to launch a dialog when app is in onStop() state?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, dialog, bundle

I'm creating a timer app that utilizes a thread. When I exit the app using the home button the timer is running fine. Usually, when the time is up a dialog is launched that asks the user for some input. This works completely fine if the app is in its onResume() state, however when the app is in its onStop() state the dialog will not launch and an error is thrown.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

How can I make it so that when the time is up and the app is NOT in the foreground the dialog is still launched. My initial thought was to save the time remaining in the bundle, but the time remaining is changing for every single tick. Then I thought about storing a boolean in the bundle mTimeRunning. However, when the time is up this value must also change. So now I'm drawing a blank. What can I possibly do so that the dialog is launched when the app is not in the foreground?

**TimerActivity.java**

```
public class TimerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimeDialogFragment.sendMinutes, 
TimeFinishDialogFragment.sendResponse, BreakFinishDialogFragment.userResponse {


// Variable to log activity state
private static final String TAG = "TimerActivity";
private static final boolean DEBUG = true;
// ^^ Variable used to log acitivty state


private Handler mHandler;
private Runnable mRunnable;

//private static final long START_TIME_MILLISECONDS = 600000;
// Below start time is for development purposes only
private static long mStartTime = 10000;
private long mTimeRemaining = mStartTime;

private boolean mTimeRunning;

private boolean mBreakTime = false;

private ProgressBar mTimeBar;
private TextView mTime;
private Button mStartPause;

private Button mSetTime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);

    if(DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "+ onCreate() +");

    mHandler = new Handler();


    mTimeBar = findViewById(R.id.time_bar);
    mTime = findViewById(R.id.text_view_time);
    mStartPause = findViewById(R.id.button_start_pause);

    mSetTime = findViewById(R.id.button_set_time);
    updateCountDownText();
    mTimeBar.setMax((int) mTimeRemaining);


    mSetTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            DialogFragment setTime = new TimeDialogFragment();
            setTime.show(getFragmentManager(),"SET_TIME_DIALOG");
        }
    });


    mStartPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(mTimeRunning){
                //pauseTimer();
                mTimeRunning = false;
                mStartPause.setText("Start");
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
            }else{
                //startTimer();
                timer();
            }
        }
    });
}

// Using a handler + anon runnable

private void timer(){
    mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mTimeRunning = true;
            mStartPause.setText("Pause");
            mTimeRemaining = mTimeRemaining - 1000;
            updateCountDownText();
            mTimeBar.incrementProgressBy(1000);
            if(mTimeRemaining > 0) {
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }else{
                // if breaktime is false
                if(!mBreakTime) {

                    DialogFragment dialog = new TimeFinishDialogFragment();
                    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(),"TIME_FINISH_DIALOG");

                    mTimeRunning = false;
                }else{
                    // launch break time up dialog.
                    mBreakTime = false;

                    DialogFragment dialog = new BreakFinishDialogFragment();
                    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "BREAK_FINSIH_DIALOG");

                }
            }
        }
    };
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable,1000);
}


public void updateCountDownText(){
    int min = (int) (mTimeRemaining / 1000) / 60;
    int sec = (int) (mTimeRemaining / 1000) % 60;

    String formattedString = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", min, sec);

    mTime.setText(formattedString);
}

public void setCountDownText(long time){
    int min = (int) (time / 1000) / 60;
    int sec = (int) (time / 1000) % 60;

    String formattedString = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", min, sec);

    mTime.setText(formattedString);
}

@Override
public void userTime(int minutes) {
    TimerActivity.mStartTime = (minutes * 60) * 1000;
    mTimeRemaining = TimerActivity.mStartTime;
    mTimeBar.setMax((int) mTimeRemaining);

    setCountDownText(mTimeRemaining);
}

@Override
public void sendResponse(int val) {
    if(val == -1){
        mTimeRemaining = TimerActivity.mStartTime;
        mTimeBar.setMax((int) mTimeRemaining);
        updateCountDownText();
        mTimeBar.setProgress(0);
        mStartPause.setText("Start");
    }else if(val == 1) {
        mBreakTime = true;
        mTimeRemaining = 15000;
        mTimeBar.setMax((int) mTimeRemaining);
        setCountDownText(mTimeRemaining);
        mTimeBar.setProgress(0);
        mStartPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        timer();
    }else {
        mTimeRemaining = TimerActivity.mStartTime;
        mTimeBar.setMax((int) mTimeRemaining);
        updateCountDownText();
        mTimeBar.setProgress(0);
        timer();
    }
}

@Override
public void userResponse(int val) {
    if(val < 0) {
        // user clicked cance
        mTimeRemaining = TimerActivity.mStartTime;
        mTimeBar.setMax((int) mTimeRemaining);
        updateCountDownText();
        mTimeBar.setProgress(0);
        mStartPause.setText("Start");
    }else {
        mTimeRemaining = TimerActivity.mStartTime;
        mTimeBar.setMax((int) mTimeRemaining);
        updateCountDownText();
        mTimeBar.setProgress(0);
        timer();
    }

    mStartPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

**TimeFinishedDialog.java**

```
public class TimeFinishDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{

private Button mCancel;
private Button mSkip;
private Button mStartBreak;

private sendResponse mResponse;
interface sendResponse{
    void sendResponse(int val);
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.time_finish_dialog_fragment, null, false);

    mCancel = view.findViewById(R.id.button_cancel);
    mSkip = view.findViewById(R.id.button_skip);
    mStartBreak = view.findViewById(R.id.button_start_break);

    mCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    mSkip.setOnClickListener(this);
    mStartBreak.setOnClickListener(this);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setView(view)
           .setTitle("Start Break?");

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setContentView(view);
    return dialog;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.button_cancel:
            mResponse.sendResponse(-1);
            getDialog().dismiss();
            break;
        case R.id.button_skip:
            mResponse.sendResponse(0);
            getDialog().dismiss();
            break;
        case R.id.button_start_break:
            mResponse.sendResponse(1);
            getDialog().dismiss();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try{
        mResponse = (sendResponse) getActivity();
    }catch (ClassCastException e){
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> when the time is up and the app is NOT in the foreground the dialog is still launched

You should not be doing this since this will interrupt the user from doing other work which they might be doing at that time and this can be irritating.

> What can I possibly do so that the dialog is launched when the app is not in the foreground?

You can show the dialog only the user is actively using your application or you can fall back to show a **notification** when the user is not using the app.

And if you desperately want to show a dialog, you can try a [dialog themed activity](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/02/05/how-to-make-your-activity-appear-like-a-dialog-box-in-android/)

Comment: Notification sounds good, but how can I make it so that after the user reads the notification and then opens up the app a dialog is already launched?